# Intel Performance Primitive IPP installation

Tags: eclipse, opencv, intel-ipp

I have installed Intel IPP on my machine, I followed specific steps where you can find it here :

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-for-linux-how-to-install-intel-ipp-for-linux/

and linked the library to my IDE which is Eclipse , it compiles perfectly but when I run the code I got this error :

error while loading shared libraries: libippcv.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

any idea what might be the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: this happened to me writting a dll that was being called from Matlab, I too needed to put the IPP bin on the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE\redist\intel64\ipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add the IPP library path to your `ld.so.conf`, and then run `sudo ldconfig`. You can check that the application is properly linked by running the following:

```
ldd <your_app_name>
```

Hope that helps!